# .htaccess directories but on server in the same directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What I want to accomplish:

mysite.com/webdevelopment/ = webdevelopment.php

mysite.com/webdevelopment/websites = websites.php

Also:

mysite.com/internetmarketing/ = internetmarketing.php

mysite.com/internetmarketing/seo = seo.php

My question is: how to do it with .htaccess? I know how to rewrite url's , but when I use:

internetmarketing/seo$ seo.php , it does not work like it should. Could you explain to me how I can achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your using Apache you can do something like this in a `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on

# /%1 -> /%1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/$
RewriteRule . /%1.php [L]

# /%1/%2 -> /%2.php but require that %1.php exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule . /%2.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I tried it but it didn't work. The url rewriting works fine (only the first 'tier' - e.g. contact/contactform/ does not work) , but my css files etc don't work. For an example , www.unicmedia.nl is my site, www.unicmedia.nl/contact (see the css files etc don't work).

Comment: Yeah `/a/b/` (with ending slash) will not work as you did not specify that in your examples :). I guess you include your css files with a relative path? then you need to be careful as the browser uses the slash to resolve the absolute URL of the css-file.

Comment: If the URLs are always suppose to end with a slash you should change `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$` to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$`

Comment: That doesn't work. Maybe it has to do with my css files like you suggest. How can I solve that? I have them linked like `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` this.

Comment: You could probably use `/css/style.css` instead, that is with a leading slash making the path absolute.

Comment: Yes that did the trick, but now the second tier does not work. e.g. www.unicmedia.nl/webdevelopment/websites

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11382/discussion-between-andre-and-mattias-wadman)